# Emboss this pattern and making it glow

Tags: modeling, lighting

[image]Are booleans the best way to emboss this object into the cover? And how would one go about making it radiate with some god rays? It seems like volumetric lighting is what im looking for I just dont know how to apply it here.

Comment: Better to map it, IMO. There's unlikely to be any need for geometry. Is the Croc-skin a height-map or a normal map?

Comment: Croc skin has a normal map!